# How to write down sound of laugh in speech

Tags: onomatopoeia

I'm listening to some dialogues in Japanese and I write them down.
I need to write down sound of laughter in sentence (speech) like in English for example

> Ha ha

What I need should have notion of *laughing at someone*. Is it just simple

> 「ハハ」

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is fine. Alternatives are:

> クスクス 'silently laughing while making fun of someone'
>   ウフフ 'smiling somewhat silently and often happily'
>   エヘヘ 'smiling because of being ashamed'
>   デへへ 'smiling with a slight implication of 変態-ness'
>   アハハ, ワハハ, ワッハッハ 'giggling'
>   ガハハ 'giggling out loud or a fat person giggling'
>   ゲラゲラ 'giggling continuously'

A famous ambiguous sentence when written in hiragana, showing the importance of having hiragana, katakana, and kanji:

> ははははははとわらった。
>   Interpretation 1: 母はハハハと笑った。
>   Interpretation 2: ハハハハハハと笑った。

Answer (score 9):

Someone pointed out to me that all of the "H" group sounds (is there a name for them?) are laughing sounds. I forgot what the nuances were, but I'll refer to this [Pera Pera Penguin's 5-minute Japanese Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121043550if_/http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/dy/columns/0002/pdf/ppp095.pdf) by Hitomi Hirayama.

> はははは - normal laugh
> ひひひひひ - conniving laugh
> ふふふふふ - creepy laugh; feminine laugh
> へへへへへ - shy laugh
> ほほほほほ - [elder] feminine laughter

Prefixing an the appropriate vowel alters the meaning:

> あはははは - conniving laugh
> いひひひひひ - [elder] feminine laughter
> うふふふふふ - creepy laugh; feminine laugh
> えへへへへへ - normal laugh
> おほほほほほ - embarrassed laugh; shy laugh

[image: ドラえもん clip with laghter]

Comment: @sawa Not sure if I get it. へへへ... They have nothing to talk about so a lot of awkward laughing?

Comment: That's right. You got it.

Comment: Woohoo! Good edit. It also illustrates the definitions I gave aren't so strict.